# Enthalpy Change

Tags: physical-chemistry, enthalpy, heat

In calculating the change of enthalpy in converting Fulminic to Isofulminic acid, would one simply take the sum of the negative enthalpies of the bonds of Isofulminic acid minus the sum of the negative enthalpies of the bonds in the Fulminic acid, following the definition of enthalpy change as heat of product - heat of reactants?

Answer (score 1):

I am not too sure what your negative enthalpies refer to. In general, when defining enthalpy change in terms of bond enthalpies, enthalpy of reaction is equal to the bond energies of the bonds broken, after substrating the bond energies of the bonds made. This is defined as such as bond making is an exothermic process and bond breaking is an endothermic process. Note that bond energy is always a positive vale (i.e. it is endothermic) as it is defined to be the energy needed as input to break a bond.

So in your case, to obtain the enthalpy change of reaction: Substract the sum of the bond energies of the bonds in isofulmunic acid from the sum of bond energies of the bonds in fulmunic acid. This would be the standard way of going about it.

Hope this helps.